# Django models foreign key not recognizing 'QueryString' BaseObject

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, docker

I am currently working on a Django 1.5.2 project within a Docker instance that speaks with a mysql database in a separate Docker instance. I am trying to create a Many to Many relationship between two tables by creating a middle table that contains two foreign keys that point to the two tables that need connecting. The problem arises when I run `python manage.py syncdb` and it spits out the following error to the terminal: `NameError: name 'QueryString' is not defined`. `QueryString` is clearly defined in my models.

***Here are my Models...***

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class QueryStringTab(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='querystringtab')
    querystring = models.ForeignKey(QueryString, related_name='querystringtab')

class QueryString(BaseObject): 
    """
    Query string holds an SQL statement and query properties for execution
    """

    server_id = models.IntegerField()
    schema = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    query = models.CharField(max_length=60000) 
    variables = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_created')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_last_edited')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    touched_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    config = models.TextField(blank=True)
    runs_started = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0) # total number of seconds spent running this query to completion
    formats = "pretty_html html json prettyjson csv excel tableau".split()
```

***Noteworthy points...***
    
1) It is recognizing the `Tag` model just fine. 
    
2) Could it have something to do with the fact that `QueryString` is a `BaseObject`
    
3) It is successfully creating the `Tag` table in the mysql database

Can anyone find anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: from what i know, if you want to use Django's automatically-generated database-access API, you need to use the models.Model class. so i suppose your instinct of #2) would be right.

Comment: What is the `BaseObject` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of QueryStringTab is before the one for QueryStringTab; so when Python evaluates the first, it has not yet seen any definition for the second and therefore reports a NameError.

Django allows you to use a string target than a class object in cases like this:

```
querystring = models.ForeignKey('QueryString', related_name='querystringtab')
```

Or, you could simply move the definition of QueryStringTab to the end.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just switched from JS to Python again and am a bit rusty on the basics. You may have just saved me from getting chewed out by my PM. Best wishes!